# Getting error while trying to setup kubernetes on debian using helm

Tags: kubernetes, debian, kubernetes-helm

While running the `helm init` I was getting an error:

```
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource (post deployments.extensions)
```

But I solved it by running :

```
helm init --client-only
```

But when I run:

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace demo demo-databases-ephemeral charts/databases-ephemeral --wait
```

I'm getting:

```
Error: serializer for text/html; charset=utf-8 doesn't exist
```

I found nothing convincing as a solution and I'm not able to proceed forward in the setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your ~/.kube/config exists and is properly set up. If not, run the following command:

```
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.config ~/.kube/config
```

Now check if kubectl is properly setup using:

```
kubectl version
```

This answer is specific to the issue you are getting. If this does not resolve the issue, please provide more error log.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your kube-dns pod not able to find api server, so it returns text/html, rather then JSON

1) Check errors in dns container apart from `Error: serializer for text/html; charset=utf-8 doesn't exist`

```
kubectl logs <kube-dns-pod> -n kube-system kubedns
```

2) Update your dns pod config with following flags:

```
--kubecfg-file=~/.kube/config <-- path to your kube-config file
--kube-master-url=https://0.0.0.0:3000 <--address to your master node
```